# increase integer size / avoid integer overflow?

Tags: ada

In FORTRAN I can change the declaration of the integer to `integer(kind = 8)` and it works.

How do I do something similar in Ada?

My program is dealing with very big numbers and it's giving me some negative number when it gets very big.

I've tried:

```
with ada.text_io; use ada.text_io;
with ada.integer_text_io; use ada.integer_text_io;
with multiplication_io; use multiplication_io;

procedure multiplication is

    type unsigned is range 0 .. 2**32-1;
    multiplier, multiplicand : unsigned;
begin

    put_line("multiplier?");
    get(multiplier);

end multiplication;
```

but I get the following errors:

```
multiplication.adb:12:05: no candidate interpretations match the actuals:
multiplication.adb:12:05: missing argument for parameter "Item" in call to "get" declared at a-tiinio.ads:70, instance at a-inteio.ads:18
multiplication.adb:12:05: missing argument for parameter "Item" in call to "get" declared at a-tiinio.ads:50, instance at a-inteio.ads:18
multiplication.adb:12:05: missing argument for parameter "Item" in call to "get" declared at a-textio.ads:239
multiplication.adb:12:05: missing argument for parameter "Item" in call to "get" declared at a-textio.ads:205
multiplication.adb:12:09: expected type "Standard.Integer"
multiplication.adb:12:09: found type "unsigned" defined at line 7
multiplication.adb:12:09:   ==> in call to "Get" at a-tiinio.ads:55, instance at a-inteio.ads:18
multiplication.adb:12:09:   ==> in call to "Get" at a-textio.ads:240
multiplication.adb:12:09:   ==> in call to "Get" at a-textio.ads:206
gnatmake: "src/multiplication.adb" compilation error
Makefile:18: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 4
```

Comment: If you enable checks, you'll get an exception rather than "some negative number". Ada has multiple integer types, and you can define  your own with any bounds you like up to the maximum supported by the compiler.

Comment: How do I define my own and use it, in terms of getting input from terminal and printing it? I need to use this as an integer to perform BEDMAS on the numbers input.

Comment: Do you have an Ada textbook or some other tutorial or reference? It will explain how to define integer types and perform I/O on them.

Comment: I've tried many things in terms of references from a textbook that I have and online (there's not much online on this).
I've tried: subtype unsigned is integer range 0 .. 2**32;
and I've tried modular types, but it doesn't seem to work as an integer.

Comment: What is `multiplication_io`?

Comment: it's a package I wrote that has two functions to perform multiplication on large numbers "Russian peasant multiplication" one function performs it recursively and the other performs it iteratively

Comment: How are those large numbers represented, and how does that relate to your `unsigned` type?

Comment: those large numbers would be entered by the user "multiplier" being the first number and "multiplicand" being the second. I need them to be integer so calculations can be performed. I don't think they relate to my unsigned type the program works fine for i.e. 2,345 * 789 = 1,850,205. when I use just an integer to declare them but fails on i.e. 23,958,233 * 5,830 = 139,676,498,390.

Comment: I would have expected a package called `multiplication_io` to do input/output of multiplications (though that doesn’t really make much sense ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t tell us what `multiplication_io` is; but if it’s to do i/o related to multiplication (whatever that might be!) you *probably* want to add `use multiplication_io;`.

I tried

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Multiplication is

   type Unsigned is range 0 .. 2**32-1;
   Multiplier, Multiplicand : Unsigned;

   package Multiplication_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO (Unsigned);
   use Multiplication_IO;

begin

   Put_Line("multiplier?");
   Get(Multiplier);

end Multiplication;
```

and it compiled just fine.

Of course, my `Multiplication_IO` should have been called `Unsigned_IO`, as @KeithThompson suggested. The point is, whatever it’s called, it’s for `Unsigned` values; it won’t work for `Integer`. You wrote `get(multiplier);`, and the only `get` that the compiler could see was the one in `Integer_Text_IO`, which is for `Integer`s. You need to read up about Ada and types! One of the e-books at  [adaic.org](http://www.adaic.org/learn/materials/) would be a start.

For larger numbers, you could look at `Long_Integer`: in GNAT, it’s

```
type Long_Integer is range -(2 **63) .. +(2 **63 - 1);
for Long_Integer'Size use 64;
```

Comment: that worked, thank you!
are you able to explain why the package x is new.. is needed?

Answer (score 1):

To define an integer type with a range of 0 to 2**32:

```
type My_Integer is range 0 .. 2**32;
```

You don't need to specify which predefined integer type it's derived from; let the compiler take care of that for you.

Incidentally, you *probably* want:

```
type My_Integer is range 0 .. 2**32-1;
```

if it should occupy 32 bits.

You also need to decide whether you want an ordinary integer type or a modular type. And whatever range you choose, it will still be possible to overflow it, with results that depends on whether you've disabled range checks or not.

For the sample code you've now added to the question, you need to instantiate `Integer_IO` for your integer type:

```
package Unsigned_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO(unsigned);
-- ...
Unsigned_IO.Get(Multiplier);
```

Comment: Throws error:
multiplication.adb:12:05: no candidate interpretations match the actuals:
multiplication.adb:12:05: missing argument for parameter "Item" in call to "get" declared at a-tiinio.ads:70, instance at a-inteio.ads:18

Comment: You haven't shown the code that causes that error. You need to instantiate `Integer_IO` for your type. Does your textbook really not cover this?

Comment: It's not clear to me that a type with `range 0 .. 2**32-1` will occupy 32 bits, without a representation clause.  3.5.4(9) says that the base type of a type defined like this is symmetric about 0, which means the base type requires 33 bits and will therefore takes 64 on many processors.  A compiler could store an integer of this _subtype_ in 32 bits, but I think 64 bits is required for arithmetic operations, at least if division, `mod`, or `rem` is involved.  (`A := 0; B := (A - 2) mod 5;` should produce what?)

Comment: Note also that if she chooses a modular type, the results will _not_ depend on whether range checks are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

If the *result* of your computations fits into regular integers (but the computation potentially overflows), you may want to check out GNAT overflow elimintation (http://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/gnat_and_program_execution.html#management-of-overflows-in-gnat). E.g. use pragma Overflow_Mode (General => Eliminated);